# ClickHouse calculate nanosecond timestamp between two DateTime64 as column DEFAULT

Tags: clickhouse

I have a ClickHouse table that contains the following schema:

```
`Start` DateTime64(9),
`End` DateTime64(9),
`Duration` Int64 DEFAULT toInt64((toDecimal64(End, 9) - toDecimal64(Start, 9)) * 1000000000),
```

`Start` and `End` are `DateTime64(9)` fields with nanosecond precision, and I also need to store the difference of these in a `Duration` field which I'd like ClickHouse to generate automatically. I had trouble finding the best way to convert `DateTime64(9)` fields to nanosecond epoch timestamps, and eventually cobbled together a solution that converts them to decimals and multiplies by a constant to give the difference in nanoseconds as an integer.

This works, I seem to be getting the correct `Duration` values, but the `* 1000000000` part seems like a smell to me. Is there a better way to do this that I'm not aware of? I looked through ClickHouse's date functions and couldn't find ones that deal with nanosecond precision, only `toUnixTimestamp()` which is only seconds precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some *nano*-specific functions (that could not be referenced in docs), let's observe them for *ClickHouse version 22.8.15.23*:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM system.functions
WHERE name ILIKE '%nano%'

/*
┌─name────────────────────┬─is_aggregate─┬─case_insensitive─┬─alias_to─┬─create_query─┬─origin─┐
│ addNanoseconds          │            0 │                0 │          │              │ System │
│ fromUnixTimestamp64Nano │            0 │                0 │          │              │ System │
│ subtractNanoseconds     │            0 │                0 │          │              │ System │
│ toUnixTimestamp64Nano   │            0 │                0 │          │              │ System │
│ toStartOfNanosecond     │            0 │                0 │          │              │ System │
│ toIntervalNanosecond    │            0 │                0 │          │              │ System │
└─────────────────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────┴──────────────┴────────┘
*/
```

This one should work for you:

```sql
SELECT
    now64() AS start,
    addNanoseconds(start, 12345) AS end,
    toUnixTimestamp64Nano(end) - toUnixTimestamp64Nano(start) AS duration

/*
┌───────────────────start─┬───────────────────────────end─┬─duration─┐
│ 2023-11-27 21:27:23.958 │ 2023-11-27 21:27:23.958012345 │    12345 │
└─────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────┴──────────┘
*/
```